# Another: Warning, too much iteration done before the next frame

Tags: python-2.7, kivy

When I run my script, I get this error:

[CRITICAL] [Clock       ] Warning, too much iteration done before the next frame. Check your code, 
or increase the Clock.max_iteration attribute

This happens when I call a method in a class that is called `class mgsApp(BoxLayout)`,
that is, when I call the method from another class.

The method is this:

```
def listCleaner(self):
    try:
        for mdw in lItem:
            self.the_mLv.adapter.data.remove(mdw)                
    except ValueError:
        pass
    #Reload list
    self.listLoader()
```

Then it reloads the list from a text file. It iterates
through that list. Here is that method that does that. 
It is in the same class with `listCleaner`, which is the
`mgsApp` class.

```
def listLoader(self):
    mslFile = os.path.isfile(mgs.strip() + "mylist.txt")
    if mslFile == True:
        with open(mgs.strip() + "mylist.txt", "r") as info:
        try:
            global lItem
            lItem = [items.strip() for items in info]
            self.the_mLv.adapter.data.extend(lItem)
            info.close()
        except IndexError:
            pass
    elif mslFile == False:
        pass
```

This is added to a `listview`, thus the line, `self.the_mLv.adapter.data.extend(lItem)`.
The user will select a item from the list and press a "Got!" button on top of a
`ActionBar`, which is an `ActionButton`. Then a popup will ask the user if they are
sure if they want to delete the item? When you press yes, you invoke a method
in that `Popup` class called `class itemToDelete(Popup):` The method is this:

```
def yesToRemove(self):
    with open(mgs.strip() + "mylist.txt", "r") as mLst:
        remove = [itemSelected] #a global variable
        tempLst = [ ]
        for line in mLst:
            for iS in remove:
                if iS in line:
                    line = line.replace(iS, ' ')
                    line = line.strip()
            tempLst.append(line)
        mLst.close()

    #Writing back the changes to "mylist.txt"
    with open(mgs.strip() + "mylist.txt", "w") as lstWb:
        for line in tempLst:
            lstWb.write(line)
        lstWb.close()

    #Re-load shopping list
    #Got to find a workaround        
    mSlReload = mgsApp() 
    mSlReload.listCleaner()

    #Check filesize of "mylist.txt"
    mLfs = os.stat(mgs.strip() + "mylist.txt")
    mLActual = mLfs.st_size

    if mLActual > 1:
        pass
    else:        
        #Remove mylist.txt
        listDone = lstFinalRemove()
        listDone.open()
```

The line:

```
mSlReload = mgsApp() 
mSlReload.listCleaner()
```

Causes the error to occur. The error, too much iteration. It seems that I
can't call anything within that mgsApp class. Even a simple print statement
to the console causes this error. By the way here is my App class:

```
class mgsAppApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.main_screen = mgsApp()
        return self.main_screen        

    def initilize_global_vars(self, *args):
        #This gives me a place on Android, to
        #write and store files to.
        global mgs
        root_folder = self.user_data_dir
        mgs = os.path.join(root_folder, ' ')

    def on_start(self):
        Clock.schedule_once(self.initilize_global_vars, -1)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.main_screen.accountChk, -1)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.main_screen.lastLst_global, -1)   

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mgsAppApp().run()
```

I tried to reproduce this error in another water down script, but It worked,
Here is that script:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string('''

<popuptest>:
    # POPUP test
    size_hint: .8, .47
    auto_dismiss: False
    title: "Popup Test"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        padding: 40
        spacing: 40  
        Button:
            text: "Print to console"
            height: 40
            width: 130
            size_hint: (None, None)
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5}
            on_press: root.printMe()
        Label:
            text: " "
        Button:
            text: "Close"
            height: 40
            width: 80
            size_hint: (None, None)
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5}
            on_release: root.dismiss()

<mgsApp>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: .200, .235, .235, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    orientation: "vertical"
    ActionBar:
        ActionView:
            use_seperator: True
            ActionPrevious:
                title: "Test App"
                with_previous: False            
            ActionButton:
                text: "Print to console"
                on_press: root.itemHandler()
            ActionButton:                
                text: "Open Popup"
                on_release: root.openPopup()
    Label:
        text: ' '
        text_size: self.size


''')

class popuptest(Popup):

    def printMe(self):
        #This should cause too much iteration!
        printing = mgsApp()
        printing.itemHandler()

class mgsApp(BoxLayout):

    def itemHandler(self):
        #print to the console
        print "Testing 123"

    def openPopup(self):
        popupWindow = popuptest()
        popupWindow.open()

class mgsAppApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.main_screen = mgsApp()
        return self.main_screen

if __name__ == '__main__':
mgsAppApp().run()
```

The script I'm working with is 1200 lines plus long, so showing it here would be not too feasible. I hope this is enough of information to maybe see where the problem is. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The code that you have put at the end reproduces your error?

Comment: You are probably creating an infinite loop, for example you could be modifying one property that changes another, and this one changes to the first one thus generating an infinite loop.

Comment: I am at work as of now, but let me check that exact python version and kivy version. The example works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in the `ActionBar' Here is my code, this is where
it would be in the kv file, or in my case, in the 'Builder.load_string':

```
<mgsApp>:
    name: "mgs"
    the_mLv: id_mLv
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29882870/
    # how-to-position-boxlayout-to-top-of-screen
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: .200, .235, .235, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    orientation: "vertical"
    ActionBar:
        ActionView:
            use_seperator: True
            ActionPrevious:
                title: "My Go Shopping"
                with_previous: False
                app_icon: "icon_tray.png"            
            ActionButton:
                text: "Got!"
                on_press: root.itemHandler()
            ActionButton:                
                text: "Refresh"
                on_release: root.listCleaner()
            ActionOverflow:
                ActionButton:
                    text: "New List"
                    #text_size: self.size
                    on_press: root.chkForNewList()
                ActionButton:
                    text: "Check Server"
                    #text_size: self.size
                    on_press: root.accountToServer()
                ActionButton:
                    text: "Logout"
                    #text_size: self.size
                    on_press: root.accountRemove()

    ListView:
        id: id_mLv
        adapter:
            ListAdapter(
            data=[ ],
            selection_mode="single",
            allow_empty_selection=True,
            cls=ListItemButton)
```

`#text_size: self.size` in the `ActionOverflow` was causing the `Warning, too much iteration` error that flooded the console. Commenting that out stopped that. Why it causes really is still to be determined. Just thought I would post this if someone runs into this same problem

Comment: Hi I was also getting this "Warning, too much iteration done before the next frame" when I tried using a Popup. I had text_size: self.size in a Label, commented it out, and it worked. Thanks!!!

Comment: @JBart Glad to hear that!